# Centos 7 Start job is running for wait for plymouth boot

Tags: centos, plymouth

Since I did the lastest update of my linux Centos 7, i have this message at the boot:

```
A start job is running fro wait for plymouth boot screen to quit
```

I am working with KDE desktop. I don't really know how to fix this issue.